# how do I access iTunes Visualizer options?

Tags: itunes, macos

I'm using iTunes 10.4 and under "menu > View > Visualizer >" there are two options, "iTunes Visualizer" or "iTunes Classic Visualizer" there's also a greyed out "Options..." menu.

The last time I used visualizer (a while ago) there were several cool visualizers to choose from like plasma shapes, and bouncing balls, and stuff.  I don't see any of that here.

Where are these options?  Were they removed?  And why is "Options..." greyed out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you upgraded to Lion?

As per [this support thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3196718?start=0&tstart=0) it seems the extra visualizers require 32-bit mode:

> Right click on iTunes.app in your Applications folder and click "Get Info". In the window that appears, click "Open in 32-bit mode" at the bottom of the "General" pane.
>
> This is a work-around, not a fix, and I have filed a bug report with Apple.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Lion.

Comment: Are there any drawbacks to running iTunes in 32-bit mode?

Comment: Don't forget that if you are already running iTunes, you'll have to close iTunes and relaunch for the changes to take effect.